# Setting a variable assets field, depending on the URL?

Tags: assets, conditional, segments

How can I set different assets fields depending on the URL?

I tried:

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == 'special' %}
   {% set assetfield = variantfield1 %}
{% endif %}

{% for asset in entry.assetfield %}     
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

But that doen't change `entry.assetfield`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably do it like so:

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == 'special' %}
    {% set assets = entry.assetfield_1 %}
{% else %}
    {% set assets = entry.assetfield_2 %}
{% endif %}

{% for asset in assets %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Clear answer, the answer of mmikkel helped me a bit in understanding why it works this way

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your original code is that you're looping through the "default" field, i.e. `entry.assetfield`, not the variable you set (`assetfield`).

@carlcs' answer should do it, though you could also set the variable w/ a [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) to make it a one-liner:

```
{% set assetField = craft.request.getSegment(1) == 'special' ? entry.assetFieldSpecial : entry.assetField %}

{% for assets in assetField %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```